# How to create a proper HTTPPost webservice method

Tags: web-services, post, asp.net-web-api, get

I am trying to do a [HTTpPost] webservice, but unfortunately without success.

My sample class is like this:

```
[RoutePrefix("CarInformation")]
public class CarInformationController : BaseApiController
{
    [HttpPost]    
    [Route("BodyStatusHistory2/{orders}")]
    public HttpResponseMessage GetHistory(string orders)
    {

        //do something with orders

    }   
}
```

Is this correct? If so, how do I call it? I tried several things from the browser but I am unable to call it.

Can I also combine

```
[HTTpGET] and [HTTpPOST] ?
```

So a method can have GET and POST? If I replace the annotation from POST to GET I can call it in the url and it is working. Unfortunately not with POST

Comment: What 'several things' have you tried?  If you type a URL into the browser, it's only going to do a `GET`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4486658/what-tools-do-you-use-to-test-your-public-rest-api

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it:

With the correct header:

```
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
```

and

```
public HttpResponseMessage GetBodyStatusHistory2([FromBody] string orders)
```

It worked

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I know, but I dont want a GET it has to be a POST. This was one of my POST calls:

POST:

```
http://localhost:59595/CarInformation/BodyStatusHistory2/
```

.

```
Host: localhost:59595
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:44.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/44.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
DNT: 1
Access-Control-Request-Method: POST
Access-Control-Request-Headers: content-type
Origin: http://localhost:51372
Connection: keep-alive
```

Body:

```
{"orders":"6320171074502,6320171074504"}
```